# Select and Populate function in mongoose is not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, populate, mongoose-populate

I am trying to get the Movie field with movie title and populating the genre collection.
But the response I am getting is the movies collection with all properties.

```
const movies = await Movie.find()
    .populate("genre", "name")
    .sort("name")
    .select("title");
```

Response I got

[
{
"_id": "623724b0bdb7598002f04b83",
"title": "Titanic",
"numberInStock": 10,
"dailyRentalRate": 5,
"genre": {
"_id": "61e923f6860764ef514a64b5",
"name": "romantic",
"__v": 0
}
},
{
"_id": "623724d6bdb7598002f04b85",
"title": "Harry Potter",
"numberInStock": 15,
"dailyRentalRate": 5,
"genre": {
"_id": "61e923da860764ef514a64aa",
"name": "action",
"__v": 0
}
}
]

Answer (score 1):

You can using (-) sign in front of the select field.
Ex:

```
const movies = await Movie.find()
  .populate("genre", "name")
  .sort("name")
  .select("title -numberInStock -dailyRentalRate");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update the query as following

const movies = await Movie.find()
.populate({ path: "name",select: "title"})